# mongoose method array of models add

Tags: node.js, methods, mongoose, schema

What I'm trying to do is create a method in mongoose that will return a total value if given an array of models. Unfortunately I really can't seem to grasp methods very well.
Here's a simpler example of what I have:

```
var Stuff = new Schema({
     portion: Number
});
```

I want to create a method that, if given var stuff1, stuff2, stuff3, it would return

```
stuff1.portion + stuff2.portion + stuff3.portion
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Shouldn't you be also passing `Stuff` into `mongoose.model`?

Comment: Can you edit your question to show an example of what you've tried to better illustrate what you're trying to do?